# amcl_pose echo results explanation

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, amcl-pose, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have amcl_pose running. After I echoed it, this is what I see. I can see that covariance consists of 36 values, so I guess it is a 6x6 matrix, however position + orientation have 7 different values. What am I misunderstanding here? How do I interpret this?

```
header: 
 seq: 81
  stamp: 
 secs: 1839
nsecs: 212000000
frame_id: map

pose: 
 pose: 

position: 
  x: -7.76006046064
  y: -1.15741912051
  z: 0.0
orientation: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.841545398193
  w: 0.540186396331

  covariance: [0.0026612296465486907, -0.0006793180004436294, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.0006793180004454058, 0.003341409476325552, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0012125460173182706]
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Why are X and Y for orientation equal to 0?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231846/amcl_pose-echo-results-explanation/) by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation of [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovariance.html) gives some explanation :

```
# Row-major representation of the 6x6 covariance matrix
# The orientation parameters use a fixed-axis representation.
# In order, the parameters are:
# (x, y, z, rotation about X axis, rotation about Y axis, rotation about Z axis)
float64[36] covariance
```

For the conversion from quaternions to fixed-axes, see [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/138541/what-is-the-proper-way-to-obtain-the-fixed-axis-covariance-matrix-from-quaternions/) and the links therein.

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-04-14**:
I thought that first (0.0026612296465486907) variable was covariance value of x axis, so if I used sqrt on it, result would be 0.0515, which shows how much robot is certain about its current position (which is ~5cm).

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-04-14**:
`covariance[0][0]` should be the variance of the linear position `x` and its square root is the standard deviation, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your orientation is given in quaternion coordinates which has 4 values.  The covariance matrix is based on the 3 euler angles roll, pitch, yaw.  You can convert between the two coordinate systems.  See [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/36848/covariance-matrix-for-the-posewithcovariance-in-odometrymsg/) post for more details.

---

Originally posted by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) with karma: 354 on 2016-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-05-21**:
Hey, do you know why X and Y for orientation are equal to 0?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-22**:
@murdock Because mobile robots navigating in a flat 2D workspace do not rotate about the X and Y axis (roll and pitch). They only rotate about the Z axis (yaw). If you convert the quaternion to Euler angles like the answer suggests you'll see that more clearly.

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2016-05-22**:
Thank you!